# Equivalent C++ nested print in python

Tags: c++, python, printing, nested-loops, equivalent

I'm trying to run this C++ statement in python and I'm having trouble placing the print in the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
          cout<<_3x3x3[i][j][k]<<" ";
        }
    }
     //print here in python
     cout<<endl;
}
```

in python:

```
_3x3x3 = [[[0 for col in range(3)] for row in range(3)] for depth in range(3)]

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            _3x3x3[i][j][k] = 1

for col in _3x3x3:
    print col
print
for row in _3x3x3:
    print row
print
for depth in _3x3x3:
    print depth
#I want to print this in the C++ style above
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            print _3x3x3[i][j][k]
```

Comment: Please post your best guess in Python and the specific problem you're having with that best guess.

Comment: what do you mean by having trouble placing it?

Comment: @I editted the post and added the python code. I would like to print out that 3d array using what I did in C++ above the python code.

Comment: And what isn't working about your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            # something here
            print _3x3x3[i][j][k],
    print
```

Comment: Gotta add that comma after the something here to prevent a newline using print.

Comment: My output was a column of ones, there should be 3 columns and 9 rows

Answer (score 0):

For variety, and future-proofing:

```
from __future__ import print_function

for i in range(3):
    print(*(_3x3x3[i][j][k] for j in range(3) for k in range(3)))
```

The difference between this and the C++ code is that this doesn't output a space at the end of each line, before the newline. That's probably a good thing, though.